# Single- or double-column table for first normal form

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, normalization

I am working on designing some new database tables in MS SQL Server 2008 R2, and I have a question about performance optimization.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm working on.  I want to keep an inventory of some devices, so here's my pre-normalized table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyDevices(
  DeviceId INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  DeviceName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyDevices_DeviceName DEFAULT '',
  IPAddress VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyDevices_IPAddress DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  SoftwareVersion VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyDevices_SoftwareVersion DEFAULT '')
```

After examining data, I notice that there are only a few software versions (we'll say 5) that repeat.  So to avoid the repetition, I create a table for the software versions.  Although the version names are unique, I figure it would be pointless to have a single-column table with the version name as the natural primary key; then I'd still have the full version name in the devices table.

```
CREATE TABLE SoftwareVersions(
  SoftwareVersionId SMALLINT IDENTITY(0, 1),
  SoftwareVersionName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  CONSTRAINT PK_SoftwareVersions PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
    SoftwareVersionId ASC
  )
)
```

The device table is now created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyDevices(
  DeviceId INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  DeviceName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyDevices_DeviceName DEFAULT '',
  IPAddress VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyDevices_IPAddress DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  SoftwareVersionId SMALLINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyDevices_SoftwareVersionId DEFAULT 0)

ALTER TABLE MyDevices WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MyDevices_SoftwareVersions FOREIGN KEY(SoftwareVersionId)
REFERENCES SoftwareVersions(SoftwareVersionId)
GO

ALTER TABLE MyDevices CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_MyDevices_SoftwareVersions
GO
```

However, the following questions come to mind:

1. I don't envision having any applications search by `SoftwareVersionId`.  Is there any point, then, in having the primary key clustered?
2. Searches would be done on the `SoftwareVersionName`, so should that be the clustered index?
3. If a clustered index is done on `SoftwareVersionName`, where should the `UNIQUE` modifier be declared?  I currently have it as part of the column definition, but I know one can create a unique index.
4. Searches on the name probably won't use less than, greater than, or a range, so should this table not have a clustered index at all?
5. Given the small number of distinct software versions, these questions may not have much of an impact.  If the number of distinct versions were closer to 1,000, would that make a difference regarding the answers to the previous questions?

Thanks!

Comment: This is likely to get closed as it is almost entirely opinion based. I would ask this, what is the point of a Version if you don't know what software it belongs to. 2005, 2008, 2008r2, 2012, 2014 by themselves mean nothing. But when you know these are versions of sql server it suddenly has some meaning. The way you are explaining this it sounds like you are only tracking the version of the OS? Having a table with versions isn't a horrible idea. It allows you some RI to ensure you don't have versions that don't exist.

Comment: @SeanLange I understand there are multiple ways to do this; I was just wondering if a certain way would make a noticeable performance difference (or other difference).

I understand that, when viewed by itself, the versions table doesn't tell you enough.  All of these devices run the same software (or maybe firmware), and anyone viewing these tables would be aware that, like you said, only a version number is tracked.  The main point of this table is simply to avoid repetition in the devices table, but it does have the added RI benefit.

Comment: Introducing a surrogate key doesn't avoid repetition.

Comment: @reaanb True.  I should have clarified that the table avoided the repetition _of long strings_ within the device table.

Answer (score -1):

To your questions:

1. you are searching with the SoftwareVersionId when you reference from the table MyDevices to SoftwareVersions.  I would create a foreign key on MyDevices.SoftwareVersionId
2. no, the SoftwareVersionName is varchar(64). I would not using a max of 64 Bytes for a clustering key, because all your nonclustered indexes you may create have to include the clustering key. A clustering key should be narrow, static, ever increasing, fixed width, non-nullable, unique.
   When you are searching for SoftwareVersionName you can create a nonclustered index with this column as key-column
3. try with your workload if it's better using a table with a clustered index or a heap and just nonclustered indexes
4. it depends on what you want to do with the both tables. test in your environment what produces more efficent plans. If you want searching with SoftwareVersionName and the referencing to the table MyDevices make sure you have an index on MyDevicesSoftwareVersionID and maybe other needed columns as included columns

Comment: 1.  I did define a foreign key; I just didn't include it in the original post.  It has been updated now to reflect that.

    And I meant I didn't anticipate searches such as:

        `SELECT * FROM SoftwareVersions WHERE SoftwareVersionId > 5`

2. That makes sense.  Thanks!

3. 

4. I'm a bit new to testing like this.  Do you mean I should turn on a certain type of statistics?

5. Thanks.  I'll take a look at the execution plans and see if I can make any sense of it.